# Android Scroll to bottom smoothly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view

I am trying to add some view to my ScrollView programmatically . Here is the xml code of view that I am trying to add. This is written in a horizontal linear layout

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="1. Sadlier ofxord "
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/delete_button"
                android:src="@drawable/delete_icon" />



        </RelativeLayout>
        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height = "2dp"
            android:background="@color/text_color"/>
```

These functions create the Views

```
private RelativeLayout createContainerLayout(){
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    layout.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 70);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    return layout;
}

private ImageButton createDeleteImageButton (){
    ImageButton button = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.delete_button);
    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete_icon);
    return button;
}

private TextView  createSetNameText(int counter , String name){
    TextView text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    text.setText(counter+". "+name);
    text.setTextSize(16);
    text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    return text;
}

private View createLineView(){
    View line = new View (getApplicationContext());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , 2);
    line.setLayoutParams(params);
    line.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
    return line;
}
```

and this is how I add the views to the ScrollView

```
lLayoutContainer.addView(rLayout);
rLayout.addView(setName);
rLayout.addView(deleteButton);
lLayoutContainer.addView(line);
```

But I get something like this in the end . The first line is the line created by XML  , and the next two lines are created programaticaly . So what is wrong with my code ? Why it creates a layout with smaller height

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both `setPadding` and the `LayoutParams` constructor, you are passing in explicit values for size. This will be absolute pixel size, irrespective of the screen density.

Please take a look at [`getDimensionPixelOffset`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelOffset%28int%29) or [`getDimensionPixelSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelSize%28int%29) instead. For example:

```
private RelativeLayout createContainerLayout(){
    final Resources r = getResources();
    final int tenDp = r.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimens.my_padding);
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    layout.setPadding(tenDp, tenDp, tenDp, tenDp);

    final int seventyDp = r.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimens.my_height);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, seventyDp);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    return layout;
}
```